# Borders around groups of plots

Tags: r

I've got 16 plots on a page, arranged in a 4x4 grid.  I'd like to have a border around each set of 2x2, but can't work out how to do it.

I initially used `layout(matrix(c(1,2,5,6,3,4,7,8,9,10,13,14,11,12,15,16), 4, 4, byrow=TRUE))` to create the correct layout, but, as far as I know, there's no way of creating margins that extend beyond both the current plot and any subsequent plot that the margin would overlap.

The 2nd approach I tried was to use `split.screen()`, thinking that any `oma()` settings would only apply to the current screen, however, it appears to apply to the whole window; for example, the following code produces a border at the outer of the whole display area, not `screen(1)`:

```
depths <- c(1:10)
split.screen(c(2,2))
screen(1)
par(oma=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(depths)
box("inner", lty="dotted", col="green")
```

Trying various things with either `box("inner")` or `box("outer")` after setting `oma` settings doesn't create the desired result.

Are there any other obvious approaches I should be trying?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a way using layout:

```
layout(matrix(c(1,2,5,6,3,4,7,8,9,10,13,14,11,12,15,16), 4, 4, byrow=TRUE))
replicate(16, hist(rnorm(100)))
par(xpd=NA)
rect( grconvertX(0.005, from='ndc'), grconvertY(0.505, from='ndc'),
     grconvertX(0.495, from='ndc'), grconvertY(0.995, from='ndc'))
rect( grconvertX(0.005, from='ndc'), grconvertY(0.005, from='ndc'),
     grconvertX(0.495, from='ndc'), grconvertY(0.495, from='ndc'))
rect( grconvertX(0.505, from='ndc'), grconvertY(0.505, from='ndc'),
     grconvertX(0.995, from='ndc'), grconvertY(0.995, from='ndc'))
rect( grconvertX(0.505, from='ndc'), grconvertY(0.005, from='ndc'),
     grconvertX(0.995, from='ndc'), grconvertY(0.495, from='ndc'))
```

Adjust it to your preferences.

Comment: Very nice.  And to think of all the time I've wasted doing conversions, when `grconvertX` was there the whole time.  Someday I have got to sit down and read through the list of basic functions.

Answer (score 9):

Try using `box("figure")`:

```
depths <- c(1:10)
split.screen(c(2,2))
screen(1)
box("figure")
split.screen(c(2,2))
par(cex=0.5)
screen(5)
plot(depths)
```